# php if OR how to?

Tags: php, logical-operators

I am trying to do if statement with OR but it wont work

```
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $refData = parse_url($ref);

    if($refData['host'] !== 'website1.com','website2.com') {
    die("...");
    }else{
<content>
}
```

The above code says unexpected syntax ','

Another one I tried is

```
    $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $refData = parse_url($ref);

    if($refData['host'] !== 'website1.com' OR $refData['host'] !== 'website2.com') {
    die("...");
    }else{
<content>
}
```

The above returns ... even though requested from the correct page

Also when there is no OR in the code with one it works fine but not when trying to add the second.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Couldn't get this working no reason why so just set CURLOPT_REFERER on website2 as website1 and and kept it as

```
if($refData['host'] !== 'website1') {
```

thank you everyone

Comment: Your logic is invalid. Instead of `OR` use `&&`

Comment: @u_mulder looks like the answer. Why put it in a comment? Maybe with a bit of code and some additional explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `!==` to `!=` and use `&&` or `OR` = `||` depending of your need

```
     $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $refData = parse_url($ref);

    if($refData['host'] != 'website1.com' || $refData['host'] != 'website2.com') {
    die("...");
    }else{
echo 'hi testing';
//run your php code here 
}
```

You problem is that you are checking if both are not identical

```
`!=` ( Not equal)



    `!==` (Not identical)

&&  example $x && $y    True if both $x and $y are true 
||  example $x || $y    True if either $x or $y is true
```

Comment: this doesn't work at all no errors just returns '...'

Comment: replace or to `||` I will fix

Comment: you are returning a tag called `<content>` what does it mean ? you want to output some var or something?

Comment: no content is just some php code getting some stuff from db and echoing it

Comment: I replaced the code if it's all ok now it should output in the browser `hi testing´

Comment: You need to have your php content inside the `if(condition){ 
//your php code here
echo  "result here"; }`

Comment: I could understand better if you show the code you are executing if the condition is true, maybe you are missing something on your code

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `in_array`.

```
  $ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  $refData = parse_url($ref);

  $array_data = ["website1.com","website2.com"];

  if(in_array($refData, $array_data))
  {
    echo "Do Something!";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "Failed!";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
||
```

Is the OR operator in PHP.

But here, you need an AND operator `&&`
Like this :

```
if($refData['host'] !== 'website1.com' && $refData['host'] !== 'website2.com')
```